# Why my NFS server can run without portmap?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have learned from this [Linux NFS-HOWTO](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s03.html) that in order to setup a NFS server, the daemon portmap must be run first.

But why I cannot find any portmap process using `ps aux | grep`.

My system is Ubuntu 12.10 and I set up my NFS server under the instruction from  [SettingUpNFSHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

Answer (score 3):

The portmap process on Ubuntu 12.10 is called "rpcbind". It's usually running on port 111. You can use the "rpcinfo" command to query it also. Hope that helps.